# Can´t get matplotlib to work with eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib, libraries, pydev

I´ve recently downloaded eclipse and pydev (im getting started in coding) and I'm trying to use matplotlib. However everytime I try to import the library I get the following message:`DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found`. I think it has something to do with Numpy?, but after reinstalling it the error keeps happening. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: You should also include information about the versions that you use such as Eclipse, PyDev, Win/Mac/Linux, matplotlib, numpy, Python. (BTW, I feel your pain. It took me a while to get Eclipse working as intended - but imho it is worth the effort).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the usual problem here is that one of your `PATH` environment variables is not correct (i.e.: usually `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBPATH or SHLIB_PATH`).

If you're using conda, make sure you select `Load conda env vars before run` (this usually takes care of the issue).

[image]

If you're not using conda (or checking that setting didn't solve it), the first step would be checking if it works in the command line.

If it does work in the command line you should copy the environment variables from the command line and set in in the interpreter environment (in that same preferences page in the `environment` tab).

Comment: Checking the load conda env did not work, and in the command line it does work. How do I copy the enviroment variables from the command line and set in in the interpreter environment?

Comment: One simple option if it works in the command line is activating the env and then starting Eclipse from that env. Otherwise, you have to call in the command line something as `set PATH` (on Windows) and then copy the output and paste it into the environment tab.